# multiple report download php adwords api

Tags: php, google-ads-api

Iam trying to download a reports for various sub-accounts under an MCC account. I am setting the clientCustomerId from within my code since I would want to loop through the various clientCustomerIds to have all the reports downloaded in one run. So far I have been testing it with one clientCustomerId but I get the following error:

An error has occurred: The client customer ID must be specified for report downloads.

I have no idea where I am going wrong. I am using AdWords API v201406:

Here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/init.php';
require_once ADWORDS_UTIL_PATH . '/ReportUtils.php';

/**
 * Runs the example.
 * @param AdWordsUser $user the user to run the example with
 * @param string $filePath the path of the file to download the report to
 */
function KeywordPerformanceReport(AdWordsUser $user, $filePath) {
  // Load the service, so that the required classes are available.
  $user->LoadService('ReportDefinitionService', ADWORDS_VERSION);

  // Create selector.
  $selector = new Selector();
  $selector->fields = array('AccountDescriptiveName', 'CampaignId', 'CampaignName', 'CampaignStatus', 'AdGroupId', 'AdGroupName', 'AdGroupStatus',
      'AverageCpc', 'AveragePageviews', 'AverageTimeOnSite', 'Id', 'Impressions', 'KeywordText', 'Clicks', 'PlacementUrl', 'TrackingUrlTemplate', 'ConversionRate', 'Conversions', 'Cost', 'Date', 'DayOfWeek', 'DestinationUrl');

  // Filter out removed criteria.
  $selector->predicates[] = new Predicate('Status', 'NOT_IN', array('REMOVED'));

  // Create report definition.
  $reportDefinition = new ReportDefinition();
  $reportDefinition->selector = $selector;
  $reportDefinition->reportName = 'Keyword performance report #' . time();
  $reportDefinition->dateRangeType = 'YESTERDAY';
  $reportDefinition->reportType = 'KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT';
  $reportDefinition->downloadFormat = 'CSV';

  // Exclude criteria that haven't recieved any impressions over the date range.
  $reportDefinition->includeZeroImpressions = FALSE;

  // Set additional options.
  $options = array('version' => ADWORDS_VERSION);

  // Download report.
  ReportUtils::DownloadReport($reportDefinition, $filePath, $user, $options);

  printf("Report with name '%s' was downloaded to '%s'.\n",
      $reportDefinition->reportName, $filePath);
}

// Don't run the example if the file is being included.
if (__FILE__ != realpath($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
  return;
}

try {
  // Get AdWordsUser from credentials in "../auth.ini"
  // relative to the AdWordsUser.php file's directory.

  $user = new AdWordsUser();
  $customerId='xxx-xxx-xxx';
  $user->SetClientId($customerId);

  // Log every SOAP XML request and response.
  $user->LogAll();

  // Download the report to a file in the same directory as the example.
  $filePath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/report.csv';

  // Run the example.
  KeywordPerformanceReport($user, $filePath);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  printf("An error has occurred: %s\n", $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: It's probably a silly question, but i assume that you are using an actual cusomterId from your MCC where you have 'xxx-xxx-xxx'? Have you had a look at the logged soap request?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use like this (Adwords Api Version : v201502)

```
$user = new AdWordsUser(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, $oauth2Info);
$user->SetClientCustomerId($clientCustomerId);
$user->LogAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally pass the customer id in when instantiating the user. This code is from v201402.

```
$user = new AdWordsUser(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, $customerID);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the function `SetClientCustomerId()` to get the data from multiple account, this was supported in previous version of API, which is now `withClientCustomerId()` present in `AdWordsSessionBuilder`.